# How to to split by word a list of strings and convert it to sublists?

Tags: python, string, list, split

I want to split the strings by word in a list of strings. I try to iterate the list however I receive an error that split is not a list method. The needed outcome is:

```
[["Hi", ",", "how", "are", "you", "?"], ["look", ":", "over", ",", "there"]
```

Code:

```
list1=["Hi, how are you?", "look: over, there"]
list2=[]
for x in list1:
    list2=list1.split()
print(list2)
```

Comment: `[s.split() for s in xs]`

Comment: it gives the same AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Regex --> `re.split`.

**Ex:**

```
import re

list1 = ["Hi, how are you?", "look: over, there"]
result = [[j for j in re.split(r"([^A-Za-z])", i) if j.strip()] for i in list1 ]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[['Hi', ',', 'how', 'are', 'you', '?'], ['look', ':', 'over', ',', 'there']]
```